# Jar files required to access Selenium class functions

Tags: selenium, jar, selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver

Currently I have included the following JAR files to playback selenium recordings using JAVA.

1. junit-4.10.jar
2. selenium-java-2.24.1.jar
3. selenium-server-standalone-2.24.1.jar

Also I have imported these packages

```
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.Selenium;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.After;
import static org.junit.Assert.fail;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
```

But with just these, I am not able to access selenium class functions like getAlert() or getConfirmation().

So are there any library files or JAR files that I have missed out on?

Comment: `getAlert()` and `getConfirmation()` are both implemented in `com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium` which is included in _selenium-java-2.24.1.jar_. What is the exact error you are getting ?

Answer (score 1):

You can download the Java Client driver package 2.25.0 from the [Selenium HQ site](http://seleniumhq.org/download/)  and then add all the jars in your project's referenced libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't imported the DefaultSelenium class which is in com.thoughtworks.selenium package so add this line to your code and it will work.

import com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium;

Comment: Hey, do have any reference link to get this jar that has this package `import com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium`